# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Hangman game

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create a Hangman game but I don't know how to properly initialize the wordDisplay array, it gives an error
this array is supposed to print out underscores for letters of the word to guess and then the underscores get replaced by letters that were guessed by the player

```
public class Hangman
{
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String strword = "wordo";
        char[] theWord = strword.toCharArray();
        int k = strword.length();
        int c;

        char[] wordDisplay;

        for(c=0;c<=k;c++)
        {
            wordDisplay[c] = '_';
        }

        int hang = 0;
        int i;

        while(hang<k+10)
        {

            System.out.println("type a letter");

            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                System.out.print( wordDisplay[i] );
            }
            char userLetter = userInput.next().charAt(0);
            for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
            {
                if(userLetter==theWord[i])
                {
                    System.out.println("a letter guessed");
                    wordDisplay[i] = theWord[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    hang++;
                }
            }


        }   
        System.out.println("you hang");
    }

}
```

Comment: `it gives an error`, which error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at test2.Hangman.main(Hangman.java:19)

Comment: I'm about to write Q&A how to write a Hangman game in Java.

Comment: You only _declared_ `wordDisplay` but never _initialized_ it so its value will always be `null`. Change `char[] wordDisplay` to `char[] wordDisplay = new char[k]` then it should work. Also in your for-loop you need to change `<=` to `<` or you'd get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: is this really Java? This code should not compile at all - the compiler is smart enough to complain about the uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
    char[] wordDisplay;

    for(c=0;c<=k;c++)
    {
        wordDisplay[c] = '_';
    }
```

write:

```
    char[] wordDisplay = new char[k+1];
    for(c=0;c<=k;c++) {
        wordDisplay[c] = '_';
    }
```

or

```
    char[] wordDisplay = new char[k];
    for(c=0;c<k;c++) {
        wordDisplay[c] = '_';
    }
```

Each object in Java must be initialized.

Comment: Eh I did that and after I type in one letter, it gives the same error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at test2.Hangman.main(Hangman.java:35)

Comment: nevermind I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array with the length you have

```
char[] wordDisplay = new char[k]
```

and change your `for` to:

```
for(c=0;c<k;c++)
  {
    wordDisplay[c] = '_';
  }
```

Keep in mind that your first index is 0

Comment: @coldcash consider accepting/ upvoting/ both if it answered your question so others are aware.

Answer (score -1):

You have not only to declare but to initialize the array. Since an array has a fixed size you should initialize it with it's size. That on the other hand is the length off the input string. So e.g:

```java
char[] wordDisplay = new char[k];
```